# jQuery scripts in the response of Ajax does not work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery $.load() function to get content from server.
the loaded content contain this:

```
<p id="p1">123</p>
<script>   
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#p1').html('ABC');
      alert($('#p1').html());
 });
</script>
```

changing text of paragraph to 'ABC' not affected to page but alert() display 'ABC'.

Answer (score 2):

I think your selector is incorrect.  $('#p') will select elements (though in principle there should be only one, but that's separate) with id "p".  Not all

elements.  So I think you either mean $('p') or $('#p1').

Answer (score 1):

If you're loading it in via .load() get rid of the surrounding $(document).ready(); bit. It's not necessary as the DOM is already loaded. Your script should just run as you'd expect.

Don't forget to add type="text/javascript" to your script tag to make sure it's not breaking anything.

If you still have trouble try just using the callback function of .load() eg.

```
  $("#somediv").load('some.html',{ /* empty data arg */ },function(){
    $("#p1").html('ABC');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

"#p" selector looks for a DOM element with id "p" - and there is nothing like that in here.

The correct selector would be "#p1".

Also, to set the text in a node, use text():
(see text(val) in http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation )

> $("#p1").text('ABC');

Answer (score 0):

Er, wouldn't the document already be 'ready' when the content is loaded? Does the alert actually fire? If so, I agree with arnab_deka: use the .text() method.

Comment: if doc ready has already been and past then any doc ready functions parsed in the future will be exectued immediately